# Perform consecutive checks

Tags: c#, math

I have to perform logic if a number is x times bigger than another number.

```
// The distance between two candles
var distance = Math.Abs(firstAggregationUpperValue - currentCandleUpperValue);

// How many times is the distance bigger than firstAggregationDifference
var times = distance / firstAggregationDifference;
```

I have to perform the following checks for `times`:

- 7 or above and below 9 (times >= 7 && times < 9)
- 9 or above and below 12 (times >= 9 && times < 12)
- 12 or above and below 16 (times >= 12 && times < 16)
- etc.

Assuming times is starting at 3 times bigger, the sequence is: 4 -> 2 -> 3.

- 3 + 4 = 7 (times >= 7 && times < 9)

Note that 4 there. The next one is `+ 2`.

- 7 + 2 = 9 (times >= 9 && times < 12)

Note that 2. The next one is `+ 3`.

- 9 + 3 = 12 (times >= 12 && times < 16)

Note 3 there. The next one is again `+ 4`.

- 12 + 4 = 16 (times >= 16 && times < 18)
- and so on

What's the best way to do that? I just don't want to hard-code 7, 9, 12, 16, 18, etc.

Comment: Store the parameters of the checks you need to perform in a data structure, and then loop through performing each check.

Comment: @John, thanks, I did it with a loop. However, if there is another solution, anyone feel free to share it.

Comment: Note that you should post your solution as an answer, not as an edit to your question. We'll be able to upvote it if you do that! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a working solution using loops.

```
int n = 3;

for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
    {
        var nextParameter = parameters[(i + 1) % parameters.Length];
        var firstPart = n + parameters[i];
        var secondPart = n + parameters[i] + nextParameter;

        if (times >= firstPart)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"times >= {firstPart} (&& times < {secondPart}) ({n} + {parameters[i]})");
        }

        n += parameters[i];
    }
}
```

Output:

```
if times == 44 =>

times >= 7 (&& times < 9) (3 + 4)
times >= 9 (&& times < 12) (7 + 2)
times >= 12 (&& times < 16) (9 + 3)
times >= 16 (&& times < 18) (12 + 4)
times >= 18 (&& times < 21) (16 + 2)
times >= 21 (&& times < 25) (18 + 3)
times >= 25 (&& times < 27) (21 + 4)
times >= 27 (&& times < 30) (25 + 2)
times >= 30 (&& times < 34) (27 + 3)
times >= 34 (&& times < 36) (30 + 4)
times >= 36 (&& times < 39) (34 + 2)
times >= 39 (&& times < 43) (36 + 3)
times >= 43 (&& times < 45) (39 + 4)
```