# Match element to closest sequence number and perform logic

Tags: c#

Look at the following chart.

[image]

By starting with the first candle, it should measure the distance between first candle's bottom/lower value and next candle's bottom/lower value and perform logic only if the next candle's distance is bigger than current's.

This is working in my code but I need to perform something specific.

**The question:**

Right now, I know how many times (`var times`) the distance is bigger than first candle's size/largeness/content/whatever you call it. Now, I have to perform checks on each 4, 2, 3 sequence. Description and more information in my previous thread: [Perform consecutive checks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58620479/perform-consecutive-checks). I did that with a loop but it can't prevent the x7 and x9 being executed everytime. It's also inefficient because imagine the distance being 1000 times bigger than candle's largeness and not only. Currently, the loop does 50 checks which limits the sequence to 90. Usually, `times` is bigger than 90. I need a better way.

The way it can made won't matter as soon as it meets the following requirements (with or without loop):

- performs logic for elements with distance bigger than current candle's distance.
- I should log save *the last* and *pre-last* matching element to the sequence. If you look at the picture, visually, you can see that the red candlestick in the most bottom with 9175.76 label has the biggest distance. It currently knows the times it can be composed of the first candle's content. It also must meet the following conditions: `> 7`, `> 9` and to get the last and pre-last matching element from the sequence. In this case, the conditions `> 7` and `> 9` are met even in the second candle.

Examples for a solved problem:

- if `times` is 13, the last matching element from the sequence should be 12 and the pre-last - 9.
- if `times` is 10, the last matching element should be 9 and the pre-last - 7
- if `times` is 53, the last matching element should be 52 and the pre-last 48.

I hope you get it. I pasted the numbers from the sequence until 90. Keep in mind that the sequence should be limitless and its limit depends on `times`' value which is currently not working in my code.

The solution is probably easily achievable, just ideas don't come outto me.

**Code:**

- firstElementDifference - first element's largeness (from top to bottom)
- distances - the distance between first candle's bottom and next candle's bottom
- times - it represents how many times the distance contains firstElementDifference.

```
public bool IsRedCandle(Candle candle)
    => candle.Open > candle.Close;

var currentCandleLowerValue = IsRedCandle(currentCandle) ? currentCandle.Close : currentCandle.Open;

var firstElement = await _botService.GetFirstElement(session.Id);
var firstElementDifference = Math.Abs(firstElement.Open - firstElement.Close);
var firstElementLowerValue = IsRed(firstElement) ? firstElement.Close : firstElement.Open;

var distance = firstElementLowerValue - currentCandleLowerValue;
var times = distance / firstElementDifference;

StringBuilder signalMsg = new StringBuilder();
signalMsg.Append($"Open time: {currentCandle.OpenTime.ToLocalTime()}{Environment.NewLine}");
signalMsg.Append($"{times} = {distance} / {firstAggregationDifference}{Environment.NewLine}");
await _notificationService.SendNotificationAsync(signalMsg.ToString());

if (session.NTimes == null || times > session.NTimes)
{
    session.NTimes = times;

    // logic
    StringBuilder signalMsg = new StringBuilder();
    signalMsg.Append($"Open time: {currentCandle.OpenTime.ToLocalTime()}{Environment.NewLine}");
    signalMsg.Append($"{times} = {distance} / {firstAggregationDifference}{Environment.NewLine}");
    await _notificationService.SendNotificationAsync($"{signalMsg.ToString()}");
}
```

```
int n = 3;
int[] parameters = new int[] { 4, 2, 3 };
for (int checks = 0; checks < 50; checks++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
    {
        var nextParameter = parameters[(i + 1) % parameters.Length];
        var firstPart = n + parameters[i];
        // var secondPart = downtrendSession.AggregationNTimes + parameters[i] + nextParameter;

        if (times >= firstPart)
        {
            if (firstPart == 7)
            {
                // x7 logic
            }
            else if (firstPart == 9)
            {
                // x9 logic
            }

            // logic for the rest
        }

        n += parameters[i];
    }
}
```

```
times >= 7
times >= 9
times >= 12
times >= 16
times >= 18
times >= 21
times >= 25
times >= 27
times >= 30
times >= 34
times >= 36
times >= 39
times >= 43
times >= 45
times >= 48
times >= 52
times >= 54
times >= 57
times >= 61
times >= 63
times >= 66
times >= 70
times >= 72
times >= 75
times >= 79
times >= 81
times >= 84
times >= 88
times >= 90
```

Output:

```
Open time: 11/5/2019 5:00:00 AM
155.2 = 23.28000000 / 0.15000000
Open time: 11/5/2019 6:00:00 AM
338.4 = 50.76000000 / 0.15000000
Open time: 11/5/2019 7:00:00 AM
339 = 50.85000000 / 0.15000000
Open time: 11/5/2019 8:00:00 AM
949.9333333333333333333333333 = 142.49000000 / 0.15000000
Open time: 11/5/2019 9:00:00 AM
1350.1333333333333333333333333 = 202.52000000 / 0.15000000
```